# reshape() command causes an error being evoked from a loop

Tags: matlab, neural-network, reshape

```
psz=length(pic)

p=0; %masking counter
for i=1:outs:(psz) % dividing in blocks
    for j=1:outs:(psz)
        p=p+1
        blocks(:,:,p)=pic(i:i+outs-1,j:j+outs-1);
        ins(:,p)=reshape(blocks(:,:,p)',1,ins')';
    end
end
```

1. so to begin with i am trying to reproduce sanger rule for pca using neural networks so if somone wants to duscuss about it or give him my code he can message me:)
2. i get the following error

   Error using reshape
   To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

   Error in train (line 30)
           ins(:,p)=reshape(blocks(:,:,p)',1,ins')';

Answer (score 0):

Converting blocks(:,:,p) to a column vector should clear the error as long as there are the same number of elements in blocks(:,:,p) as the row length of ins

```
col_vec = blocks(:,:,p);
```

ins(:,p) = col_vec(:);

Comment: it doesnt work,..p =

     1

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in train (line 33)
ins(:,p) = col_vec(:);

Answer (score 0):

The size of `blocks(:,:,p)` is `outs`-by-`outs` so to make a column vector, it has to be `(outs*outs)`-by-`1`.  To do this, the command would be:

```
ins(:,p)=reshape(blocks(:,:,p)',outs*outs,1); % no need for '
```

**However**, be sure that `size(ins,1)` is `outs*outs` or it won't work.  What is the size of `ins` (and `blocks`, out of curiosity)?  Also, be sure you really want the `'` on `blocks` because the command will work with or without it.

Comment: sinze(ins,1) =1 so it doesnt work..i get the same error "elements cannot change" and i get p=1.. 

blocks : 20x20 double
ins:160

Comment: Do you initialize `ins` or are you trying to grow it?  You may want to pre-allocate `ins`.  Also, what about `blocks`?  Is it initialized somewhere?